# Rails / Factory Girl: Mutual presence validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have an association between two rails models, 'Project' and 'Step', such that a project has many steps. A step requires a project_id, and a project requires at least one step to be valid...I'm wondering how to create this in factory girl without recursion problems.

Currently, my factories look like this:

```
factory :project do
  #...
  steps { |s| [s.association(:step)] }
end

factory :step do
  #...
  association :project
end
```

Which, of course, returns a 'stack level too deep' error due to recursive associations. Problem is, I need both values to be populated.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :steps
end

class Steps < ActiveRecords::Base
  belongs_to :project
  validates :steps, :presence => true
end
```

I think this might work as a factory:

```
factory :project do
  after(:build) do |project|
    project.steps << FactoryGirl.create(:step)
  end
end

factory :step do
end
```

And you could use in it a project.spec.rb like this:

```
it "must have a step to be valid" do
  expect(FactoryGirl.create(:project)).to be_valid
end
```

I am shooting from the hip, so sorry if this doesn't work.  I think this is the general idea, in any case.